# Не работают 2 функции WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Не добавляются категории и теги к товару ( WC_Product ). set_category_ids , set_tag_ids failed

Не могу добавить категорию к товару WooCommerce.

Причем думаю, что тут вообще проблема в какой-то ерунде.

Работаю через WC Product.

**Не работает set_category_ids и set_tag_ids.**

Вот весь код **functions.php**:

```
<?php
$product = new WC_Product;
$product->set_name("товар");
$product->set_regular_price('150');
$set_cat =  $product->set_category_ids( array(17) );
$set_tag = $product->set_tag_ids( [18, 19] );
$product->save();

var_dump($set_cat);
var_dump($set_tag);
```

Товар создается с именем "товар" и ценой в 150, но категории и тегов **нет**.

Var_dump-ы сегодня выдают 2 **NULL-а**, а вчера выдали объект с ошибкой `invalid taxonomy`.

Хотя я ничего не менял. Странно.

Wordpress 4.9.6 ,
тема новая(index.php, style.css, functions.php),  WooCommerce 3.4.3.
//т.е. все свежее

И еще одно, за 1 обновление страницы **+2 товара**(а не 1),
т.е. код как бы срабатывает 2 раза. Решил это проверить, ну мало ли, поставил echo рядом.  echo отработало **1 раз**, но товару уже добавилось не 2, а 5 :D

И чем больше товаров имеется, тем больше создаётся.

//было 71, обновил, стало 90.

Вот скрины из бд(terms и taxonomy)

**terms:**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**term_taxonomy:**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

для решения этой задачи нужно вывести код на страницу шаблона

Comment: Во-первых, тема самопальная, как я понимаю. Это самый вероятный источник проблем. Смените её на стандартную 2017 и посмотрите, что будет. Во-вторых, нельзя запихивать исполняемый код прямо в functions.php. Он будет исполняться на каждый ajax (что WC делает легко) и на каждый heartbeat. Ваш код должен быть привязан к какому-то хуку. Например, wp_footer. Он не срабатывает при ajax и heartbeat.

Comment: не, в этом и прикол, что в обычных темах тоже самое, поэтому и юзал в новой

Comment: что насчет functions.php , замечание важное, но мне просто нужно 1-но нормальное создание товара(тест так сказать).

Comment: Чтобы гарантированно получить одно срабатывание, выводите код в хук. Или создайте пустую страницу, файл шаблона, назначьте этот шаблон странице.

Comment: вы гений!)) вывел код в index.php и все стало на места)))

Comment: Не гений, а просто несколько более опытный)

Comment: мужик , я на эту ..., скажем мягко,  херацию, убил 3 дня, все нормально, побудь гением). Так и знал что там будет что-то из оперы страница не та, скобки не те стоят, и т.д.))

Comment: Там не ерунда. Проблема в том, что надо понимать порядок загрузки WordPress и этапы загрузки при отображении страницы и внутренних запросах типа ajax и heartbeat.

Comment: ясненько, ну тогда тем более спасибо)